# How to resolve unfound module in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm working on Angular's [Tour de Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) and am having an issue when importing from 'angular-in-memory-web-api'.

The line of code:

> import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

The error:

> ERROR in C:/angularProjects/my-app/src/app/app.module.ts (1,35): Cannot find module 'angular-in-memory-web-api'

**How can I resolve this issue?**

I'm new to the framework and as far as I can tell the 'angular-in-memory-web-api' is the updated 'angular2-in-memory-web-api' and should work.

**Edit:**
The below comments have answered the question. Be sure to download the package -

> npm install angular-in-memory-web-api

Comment: Instead of getting to invloved with the Tour de Heroes I think you should digg into Angular CLI https://cli.angular.io/ Thats the "new" way of doing Angular

Comment: did you `npm install angular-in-memory-web-api`?

Comment: Did you install it with npm? `npm i angular-in-memory-web-api`

Comment: @Everest Yes; and it has now resolved the issue! Thank you, it was an oversight of the instructions on my part.